# Hazelcast - huge deserialization overhead

Tags: serialization, hazelcast

I keep a lot of small objects in distributed cache. Most operations are local meaning they access data at the very same node (I'm using partition awareness functionality). Even though the data is at the same node Hazelcast still does need to deserialize item which consumes a lot of memory and makes application crash with *OutOfMemoryError* for more vertices and more operations being performed on them in parallel. I know that there is a *near-cache* which I could use along with *cache-local-entries* and *data-format* equal to *OBJECT* but this does not fit well because I do some mutating operations on this data. I also used *IdentifiedDataSerializable* for data stored and everything which is being serialized so no way to gain anything from there I suppose.

Here's sample OOM error stacktrace (it gets thrown at the nodes side, not at the client side):

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.ensureAvailable(ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.java:359)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.write(ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.java:70)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:75)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.writeByteArray(ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.java:263)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.writeData(ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.java:376)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.MapEntries.writeData(MapEntries.java:141)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.write(DataSerializableSerializer.java:197)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.write(DataSerializableSerializer.java:49)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.write(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:43)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.writeObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:249)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.writeObject(ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.java:370)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.operations.PartitionIteratingOperation$PartitionResponse.writeData(PartitionIteratingOperation.java:289)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.write(DataSerializableSerializer.java:197)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.write(DataSerializableSerializer.java:49)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.write(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:43)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.writeObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:249)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.writeObject(ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.java:370)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.responses.NormalResponse.writeData(NormalResponse.java:91)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.write(DataSerializableSerializer.java:197)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.write(DataSerializableSerializer.java:49)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.write(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:43)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:151)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:125)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OutboundResponseHandler.send(OutboundResponseHandler.java:88)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OutboundResponseHandler.sendResponse(OutboundResponseHandler.java:64)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.Operation.sendResponse(Operation.java:338)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.operations.PartitionIteratingOperation$OperationResponseHandlerImpl.sendResponse(PartitionIteratingOperation.java:219)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.operations.PartitionIteratingOperation$OperationResponseHandlerImpl.sendResponse(PartitionIteratingOperation.java:207)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.Operation.sendResponse(Operation.java:338)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.sendResponse(OperationRunnerImpl.java:279)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.handleResponse(OperationRunnerImpl.java:270)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:187)
Jun 11, 2017 9:57:51 PM com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.PartitionWideEntryWithPredicateOperation
SEVERE: [10.6.3.57]:5701 [kpts-cluster] [3.8] Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.ensureAvailable(ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.java:359)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.write(ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.java:70)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:75)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.writeByteArray(ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.java:263)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.writeData(ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.java:376)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.MapEntries.writeData(MapEntries.java:141)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.write(DataSerializableSerializer.java:197)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.write(DataSerializableSerializer.java:49)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.write(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:43)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.writeObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:249)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.writeObject(ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.java:370)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.operations.PartitionIteratingOperation$PartitionResponse.writeData(PartitionIteratingOperation.java:289)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.write(DataSerializableSerializer.java:197)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.write(DataSerializableSerializer.java:49)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.write(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:43)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.writeObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:249)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.writeObject(ByteArrayObjectDataOutput.java:370)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.responses.NormalResponse.writeData(NormalResponse.java:91)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.write(DataSerializableSerializer.java:197)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.write(DataSerializableSerializer.java:49)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.write(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:43)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:151)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toBytes(AbstractSerializationService.java:125)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OutboundResponseHandler.send(OutboundResponseHandler.java:88)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OutboundResponseHandler.sendResponse(OutboundResponseHandler.java:64)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.Operation.sendResponse(Operation.java:338)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.operations.PartitionIteratingOperation$OperationResponseHandlerImpl.sendResponse(PartitionIteratingOperation.java:219)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.operations.PartitionIteratingOperation$OperationResponseHandlerImpl.sendResponse(PartitionIteratingOperation.java:207)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.Operation.sendResponse(Operation.java:338)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.sendResponse(OperationRunnerImpl.java:279)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.handleResponse(OperationRunnerImpl.java:270)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:187)
```

And this is how it looks like in Hazelcast mancenter[image: mancenter]

This is when it's almost crashing. Any bigger problem would fail.

[image: mancenter 2]

**What is interesting is it does not matter how many nodes am I going to use. They will still consume much memory space and still will fail.** So it's not about storing data but about ability to retrieve it...

Is there any other way to make deserialization consume less memory?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to avoid the overhead of de-serialization is to store the actual data in a static map inside each node and use the Hazelcast executor as a router to route your requests to the node containing that data.
The `IExecutorService.submitToKeyOwner()` will route the request to the node owning the segment key, inside that node you can maintain the actual value in a static map.
Please note that, in this approach you need to take care of cleaning up the local static map yourself. Though you can make use of the MapEvent listeners to handle the cleanup.

Comment: I guess I might use WeakHashMap for that - just "my own cache" activated only for local reads.

Comment: Let me know how did it go.